# Replace substring with variable of same name between two % signs without using replace or regex

Tags: python, string, replace

```
user = 'Peter'
location = 'Quahog'
friend = 'Stewie'
string = 'my name is %user% and i live in %location%, and my son is %friend%.'
```

The expected output would be

> my name is Peter and i live in Quahog, and my son is Stewie.

The solution is expected to be O(N) time complexity, and there can any number of variables. The % symbols can also be inside words.

Comment: How about using f-string? `string = f'my name is {user} and i live in {location}, and my son is {friend}'`

Comment: @J.Choi There can be more variables, so that wasn't accepted as the solution. And how would one replace the % symbols with curly brackets without regex or replace?

Comment: if you convert your variables to a dict, you could loop on them and use find() and replace it with string operations.
Is there any reason you dont want to use replace and regex?

Comment: Those were the problem contraints

Comment: I agree that one cannot convert % to bracket without string operations. However, (1) why the use of string operation is forbidden? Is there any practical reason? (2) There should be some process that generates strings with % symbols. Therefore, it would be possible to modify the process to use brackets.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really a pythonic way to approach it. I'd rather use dictionary or f-string, but that's what the interviewer asked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why to do this, since there are functions ready for that, but... here it is, friend

```py
def my_crazy_function(patterns:dict,text:str):
    IDENTIFIER = '%'
    inside_key = False 
    current_key = ''
    generated_text = ''
    for char in text:
        if char == IDENTIFIER:
            #means end the key
            if inside_key:
                #makes the replace 
                generated_text+=patterns[current_key]
                #flips to False 
                inside_key = False 
                #reset current key
                current_key= ''
            else:
                #means start inside key
                inside_key = True 
            #the "%" char is ignored on string            
            continue 

        if inside_key:
            current_key+=char 
        else:
            generated_text+=char 
    return generated_text        


patterns ={
    'user':'Peter',
    'location':'Quahog',
    'friend':'Stewie'
}

string = 'my name is %user% and i live in %location%, and my son is %friend%.'

r = my_crazy_function(patterns,string)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing it (without using regex, or python string methods), depending if you can put the variables in a dict or not. If you can, I will do it like this:

```
variables = {
    'user': 'Peter',
    'location': 'Quahog',
    'friend': 'Stewie'
}

string = 'my name is %user% and i live in %location%, and my son is %friend%.'
res = ''
pattern = None
for char in string:
    if char == '%':
        if pattern is None:
            pattern = ''
        else:
            res += variables[pattern]
            pattern = None
    else:
        if pattern is None:
            res += char
        else:
            pattern += char
print(res)
```

The complexity is still O(N), because the string is iterated only once, and python dict get method is O(1).

Otherwise, if you are forced to use undeterminated independent variables, the solution will be like this:

```
user = 'Peter'
location = 'Quahog'
friend = 'Stewie'

string = 'my name is %user% and i live in %location%, and my son is %friend%.'
res = ''
pattern = None
for char in string:
    if char == '%':
        if pattern is None:
            pattern = ''
        else:
            res += globals()[pattern]
            pattern = None
    else:
        if pattern is None:
            res += char
        else:
            pattern += char
print(res)
```

You should change the `globals()[pattern]` to `locals()[pattern]` if the variables are defined inside the function. In the case you dont know where the variables are defined, you can use `eval(pattern)`, but i dont recomend that option, because enables code execution inside %%.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses `eval` to find target variables. However, it should be carefully used because the use of `eval` can be problematic in many cases.

The phrase `%%` results in EOF error in this code. If you don't want it, check `(idx_start + 1) == idx_end`.

```
user = 'Peter'
location = 'Quahog'
friend = 'Stewie'
string = 'my name is %user% and i live in %location%, and my son is %friend%.'
```

```
idx_start = None
idx_end = None

string_new = ''

for idx, ch in enumerate(string):
    if ch != '%':
        if idx_start is None:
            string_new = string_new + ch
    
    else:
        if idx_start is None:
            idx_start = idx
        else:
            idx_end = idx
            
            string_new += eval(string[idx_start+1:idx_end])
            
            idx_start = None
            idx_end = None
```

```
string_new
> 'my name is Peter and i live in Quahog, and my son is Stewie.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry. Gilfoyle is here to help you out.

```
vocab_dict = {"user" : 'Peter',
              "location" : 'Quahog',
              "friend" : 'Stewie'}

sentence = 'my name is %user% and i live in %location%, and my son is %friend%.'

def fill_sentence(sentence, vocab_dict):
    special_char = "%"
    odd_flag = False
    
    word_found = ""
    generate_op = ""

    for char_i in sentence:
        if char_i == special_char and not odd_flag:
            odd_flag = True
            continue

        elif char_i == special_char and odd_flag:
            generate_op += vocab_dict[word_found]
            odd_flag = False
            word_found = ""
            continue

        elif odd_flag:
            word_found+= char_i
        else:
            generate_op+= char_i

    return generate_op

        

fill_sentence(sentence, vocab_dict)
```

Output :

```
my name is Peter and i live in Quahog, and my son is Stewie.
```